# Translate pgSQL Function to Snowflake

Tags: postgresql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, plpgsql

I migrated my Postgres database to Snowflake, but I am having a hard time translating a pgSQL function to a Snowflake UDF.

Before posting the script, here's a summary of what my function should do.
The function uses three tables out of my database:

```
 -- events
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events (
    id bigint NOT NULL autoincrement start 1 increment 1 PRIMARY KEY,
    odb_created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    event_time timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    device_type integer NOT NULL,
    event_type integer NOT NULL,
    ticket_type integer NOT NULL,
    card_nr character varying(100),
    count integer DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
    manufacturer character varying(200),
    carpark_id bigint
); 

 -- durations
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS durations (
    id bigint NOT NULL autoincrement start 1 increment 1 PRIMARY KEY,
    odb_created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    event_id_arrival bigint,
    event_id_departure bigint,
    event_time_arrival timestamp without time zone,
    event_time_departure timestamp without time zone,
    card_nr character varying(100),
    ticket_type integer,
    duration integer,
    manufacturer character varying(200),
    carpark_id bigint
);

--properties
create or replace TABLE PROPERTIES (
    PROP_KEY VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    PROP_VALUE VARCHAR(250),
    primary key (PROP_KEY)
);
```

The event table regroups all events which may be entries or exits.
The duration table regroups the same information as the events, but additionally, it contains the duration between an entry and an exit.
The properties table is used as reference for new calculations.

**Entries that have already been calculated cannot be calculated again, this is why we insert the id from the events table as:**

- event_id_arrival if it is an entry (device_type 1)
- event_id_departure if it is an exit (device type 2)

**Here is some sample data to recreate the tables and fill them:**

**EVENTS**
[image]

```
INSERT INTO public.events (id, odb_created_at, event_time, device_type, event_type, ticket_type, card_nr, count, manufacturer, carpark_id) VALUES(188160996, '2021-10-02 04:28:26.338', '2021-10-01 09:14:41.32', 1, 2, 11, '03998988030897300007782', 1, 'XX', 1852);
INSERT INTO public.events (id, odb_created_at, event_time, device_type, event_type, ticket_type, card_nr, count, manufacturer, carpark_id) VALUES(188160790, '2021-10-02 04:28:26.248', '2021-10-01 09:31:10.94', 2, 2, 11, '03998988030897300007782', 1, 'XX', 1852);
INSERT INTO public.events (id, odb_created_at, event_time, device_type, event_type, ticket_type, card_nr, count, manufacturer, carpark_id) VALUES(188146489, '2021-10-02 04:26:55.069', '2021-10-01 10:03:01.57', 1, 2, 500, '01479804030429500089598', 1, 'XX', 1563);
INSERT INTO public.events (id, odb_created_at, event_time, device_type, event_type, ticket_type, card_nr, count, manufacturer, carpark_id) VALUES(188146069, '2021-10-02 04:26:54.852', '2021-10-01 11:49:58.45', 2, 2, 500, '01479804030429500089598', 1, 'XX', 1563);
INSERT INTO public.events (id, odb_created_at, event_time, device_type, event_type, ticket_type, card_nr, count, manufacturer, carpark_id) VALUES(188161161, '2021-10-02 04:28:26.372', '2021-10-01 18:44:33.62', 1, 2, 11, '03998988030897300007782', 1, 'XX', 1852);
INSERT INTO public.events (id, odb_created_at, event_time, device_type, event_type, ticket_type, card_nr, count, manufacturer, carpark_id) VALUES(188160950, '2021-10-02 04:28:26.329', '2021-10-01 18:45:51.903', 2, 2, 11, '03998988030897300007782', 1, 'XX', 1852);
INSERT INTO public.events (id, odb_created_at, event_time, device_type, event_type, ticket_type, card_nr, count, manufacturer, carpark_id) VALUES(188161227, '2021-10-02 04:28:26.374', '2021-10-01 23:21:18.58', 1, 2, 11, '04139733030897300003136', 1, 'XX', 1852);
INSERT INTO public.events (id, odb_created_at, event_time, device_type, event_type, ticket_type, card_nr, count, manufacturer, carpark_id) VALUES(188160974, '2021-10-02 04:28:26.334', '2021-10-01 23:24:03.29', 2, 2, 11, '04139733030897300003136', 1, 'XX', 1852);
INSERT INTO public.events (id, odb_created_at, event_time, device_type, event_type, ticket_type, card_nr, count, manufacturer, carpark_id) VALUES(188239864, '2021-10-03 04:24:43.345', '2021-10-02 06:49:55.97', 1, 2, 11, '01719400030897300061410', 1, 'XX', 1852);
INSERT INTO public.events (id, odb_created_at, event_time, device_type, event_type, ticket_type, card_nr, count, manufacturer, carpark_id) VALUES(188239649, '2021-10-03 04:24:43.308', '2021-10-02 07:02:08.72', 2, 2, 11, '01719400030897300061410', 1, 'XX', 1852);
```

**Once those Events are filled, we run the function and obtain the following values in the duration table. The function found the entries that matched and calculated the duration. Afterwards it inserted them to the duration table and updated the properties table.**
[image]

**Function**

My function searches for rows in the table **events** with the same **card_nr** and which are only of device_type 1 (= entry) and device_type 2 (= exit). Once it has found a match, it calculates the duration between the first entry and the second entry and inserts it in the table **duration**.

To do:

1. Find two events with same card_nr and device_type 1 and device_type 2 in the table **events**
2. Calculate the duration between entry 1 and entry 2, insert it into the **duration** table.
3. The properties table is then used as reference for newer imports.

In pictures:

1. Events
   [image: Events]
2. Function runs, durations outcome
   [image: Durations]
3. Properties

[image]

Here is the function:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.calculateduration()
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE

     arrived_entryqwr RECORD;
     departed_entry RECORD;  

     durationLimitDays INTEGER := -1;
     durationLimitDate TIMESTAMP := '1970-01-01 00:00:00';
     
     cursorQuery text;
     cursorEvent refcursor;
     
     maxEventTime TIMESTAMP;
     
BEGIN
    -- DELETE FROM durations;

    -- start date   = DURATION.LIMIT.DATE
    -- end date     = now - DURATION.LIMIT.DAYS
    SELECT PROP_VALUE INTO durationLimitDays FROM properties WHERE prop_key = 'DURATION.LIMIT.DAYS';
    SELECT PROP_VALUE INTO durationLimitDate FROM properties WHERE prop_key = 'DURATION.LIMIT.DATE';
    RAISE NOTICE 'Parameter duration limit days ''%'' , duration limit date ''%''', durationLimitDays, durationLimitDate;
    
    --  AND e.event_time < to_char(now(), ''YYYY-MM-DD'')::date - (''42 month''::interval)
    cursorQuery:='SELECT e.id, e.card_nr, e.event_time, e.ticket_type, e.device_type, e.manufacturer, e.carpark_id
                  FROM events e 
                  WHERE e.event_time >= ''' || durationLimitDate || '''
                  AND e.device_type IN (1,2) AND event_type=2
                  AND e.manufacturer like ''XX''
                  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT d.event_id_arrival FROM durations d WHERE d.event_id_arrival = e.id)
                  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT d.event_id_departure FROM durations d WHERE d.event_id_departure = e.id)
                  ORDER BY e.card_nr, e.event_time, e.carpark_id';
                  -- AND e.event_time < ''2016-01-05 00:00:00'' 
    OPEN cursorEvent SCROLL FOR EXECUTE cursorQuery;

    LOOP
        FETCH cursorEvent INTO arrived_entry;
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
        IF arrived_entry.device_type=1 THEN
            FETCH cursorEvent INTO departed_entry;
            EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
            
            -- same card number and same car park
            IF arrived_entry.card_nr=departed_entry.card_nr AND arrived_entry.carpark_id=departed_entry.carpark_id THEN
                IF departed_entry.device_type=2 THEN
                    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO durations VALUES (nextval(''durations_id_seq''), ''' || current_timestamp || ''',' || arrived_entry.id || ',' || departed_entry.id || ',''' || arrived_entry.event_time || ''',''' || departed_entry.event_time 
                                                              || ''',''' || arrived_entry.card_nr || ''',' || arrived_entry.ticket_type || ',' 
                                                              || date_part('epoch', departed_entry.event_time::timestamp - arrived_entry.event_time::timestamp) || ', ''' || arrived_entry.manufacturer || ''',' 
                                                              || arrived_entry.carpark_id || ')';
                ELSE 
                    -- repeated entry found - refresh entry with the repeated one 
                    -- RAISE NOTICE 'Unexpected entry after entry found at event id ''%'' and card number''%''', arrived_entry.id, arrived_entry.card_nr;
                    FETCH PRIOR FROM cursorEvent INTO arrived_entry;
                END IF;
            ELSE
                -- card number or car park changed - refresh to changed card number / car park
                -- RAISE NOTICE 'Unexpected card number or car park change found at event id ''%'' and card number''%''', arrived_entry.id, arrived_entry.card_nr;
                FETCH PRIOR FROM cursorEvent INTO arrived_entry;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cursorEvent;
    
    -- update duration limit date ( = MAX(event_time) - durationLimitDays)
    EXECUTE 'SELECT MAX(event_time) FROM events WHERE event_time >= ''' || durationLimitDate || '''' INTO maxEventTime;
    SELECT (maxEventTime - (durationLimitDays ||' day')::interval) INTO durationLimitDate;
    EXECUTE 'UPDATE properties SET PROP_VALUE=''' || durationLimitDate || ''' WHERE prop_key =''DURATION.LIMIT.DATE''';
    RAISE NOTICE 'Add new DURATION.LIMIT.DATE to ''%''', durationLimitDate;
        
END;
$function$
;
```

And here is an attempt at trying to reproduce it or at least some part of it:

```
WITH x AS (select *
from events
match_recognize (
    partition by card_nr
    order by event_time
    measures match_number() as match_n
        , first(id) as event_id_arrival
        , last(id) as event_id_departure
        , first(event_time) as event_time_arrival
        , last(event_time) as event_time_departure
        , timestampdiff('second', first(event_time), last(event_time)) as duration
        , TICKET_TYPE AS TICKET_TYPE 
        , MANUFACTURER AS MANUFACTURER 
        , CARPARK_ID AS CARPARK_ID 
        , ODB_CREATED_AT AS ODB_CREATED_AT 
        , id AS id
    one row per match
    pattern(arr dep)
    define arr as device_type=1
        , dep as device_type=2
))
SELECT durationseq.nextval as id, ODB_CREATED_AT, event_id_arrival, event_id_departure, event_time_arrival, event_time_departure, CARD_NR, TICKET_TYPE, duration, MANUFACTURER, 
CARPARK_ID FROM x
```

Few things that I need to cover as well:

1. I should filter on the manufacturer to always be 'XX' since there are manufacturers like YY or ZZ
2. In our select, we should only calculate the durations where events.event_time >) durationLimitDate from properties
3. I need to make sure that the event_id_arrival and event_id_departure are not in the target table already to avoid duplicates
4. Once I inserted the calculations to the duration table, I must update the durationLimitDate in the properties. Knowing that durationLimitDate = (Max(event_time) - durationLimitDays))

Comment: Can you help us create sample data and desired results, to make sure we are solving this properly?

Comment: Hi @FelipeHoffa I just edited my post and added the data with input and output expected

Answer (score 1):

Partial solution - with [`MATCH_RECOGNIZE`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/match_recognize.html) it's easy to find these patterns.

I tried this with the provided sample data, and the results look good:

```sql
select *
from events
match_recognize (
    partition by card_nr
    order by event_time
    measures match_number() as match_n
        , first(event_time) as event_time_arr
        , last(event_time) as event_time_dep
        , first(id) as event_id_arr
        , last(id) as event_id_dep
        , timestampdiff('second', first(event_time), last(event_time)) as duration
    one row per match
    pattern(arr dep)
    define arr as device_type=1
        , dep as device_type=2
);
```

[image]

All you need now is to insert these results into the correct destination tables as desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I expended it a bit and added the columns I needed. There are a few more important things I need to cover. I have added them on the bottom of the post to keep the comments clean!